# Invoking Oracle stored procedure from Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sqlplus

**Situation** : I have a shell script through which I have to invoke an Oracle stored procedure, called *my_stored_procedure*. The stored procedure works fine when executed individually.

**Problem**: Within the script, I have code something like this:

```
sqlplus -s /@Credentials <<EOF
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
       i_am_a_variable number(10);
begin
       my_stored_procedure();
end;
/
EXIT;
EOF
```

The error message output is:

```
warning: here-document at line 22 delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**What I've tried** : I guess-worked things like << EOD > and << EOF > logfile.log
but they didn't work.

Any help in this regard shall be helpful.

Comment: Go to the end of your script, and add a RETURN (Enter) there: `EOF<-- add a RETURN here`.

Comment: It didn't work. Actually I have further code after the EOF also. Is that an issue ?

Comment: Roadowl, I also created another file called myProc.sql, and am trying to invoke the stored procedure from there. From my main shell script, I call myProc.sql.

Pretty much the same code is there in myProc.sql too, but it throws an error, "identifier my_stored_procedure must be declared".